# Is there a more elegant way of calling a .ready with .events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to be as DRY as possible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w= $(window).width();
    w-= (w-6) % 266;
    if (w<272) w= 272;
    $('#grid_container').width(w);
});
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);
function resizeFrame() {
    var w= $(window).width();
    w-= (w-6) % 266;
    if (w<272) w= 272;
    $('#grid_container').width(w);
};
```

Comment: It might be worth nothing that document ready, and window load are not the same events.

Comment: Without document ready, the page loads then sets the width. With document ready it loads and if I change the page size then it changes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function:

```
$(window).bind('load resize', resizeFrame);
```

Notice that you can specify multiple events to `bind` by separating them with a **space** like shown above.

You can also check which event is triggered with `type` property of event object like this:

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function(e){
  alert(e.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want this:

```
$(window).bind("load",resizeFrame);

$(window).bind("resize",resizeFrame);
```

EDITED:

[http://www.jsfiddle.net/t9fuH/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/t9fuH/1/)

The more compressed option would be:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", resizeFrame);

function resizeFrame() {
    var w= $(window).width();
    w-=((w-6) % 266);
    w=w<272?272:w;    
    $('#grid_container').width(w);
};
```